# how to change my app's target API level from 29 to 30 in ionic android

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic5

Created an ionic android app with the Cordova plugin. When tried to upload the generated apk file to the play store, got an error :

> "Your app currently targets API level 29 and must target at least API level 30 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 30".

Corrected and uploaded the apk, next time while trying to upload the newly generated apk got the same error, Is any persistent solution for it??

Corrected in config.xml, do I need to change anywhere else?

[image]

> > ionic version: 5.4.16
> > cordova version: 11.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your Cordova CLI to version 11, then it will download cordova-android 10.x when you run `cordova platform add android` that already target SDK 30 by default.
If you already have a cordova-android platform, you'll have to remove it first and also remove whitelist plugin as it's not integrated into the platform

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-whitelist
cordova platform add android
```